# How to reassign Global variables c++

Tags: c++

Why can't I reassign global variables int x , like i do in python? But works fine if i put it in function?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int x = 30;
x = 40;

int main() {
    cout << x;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
};
```

Thanks I'm new to c++

Answer (score 1):

At the global scope in C++, you don't assign variables at all. You can only ***initialize*** them. The statement `x=40` is meaningless because it's not defined when the assignment is going to happen.

What may have confused you is that one of the ways of initializing a C++ variable looks a lot like assignment.  You can tell the difference because initialization with `=` happens in the context of a declaration, so the type name precedes the variable name.

You *can* assign new values to global variables, if they're not declared `const`, but this has to happen within a statement block  --- That is, inside a function of some sort. `main` will do for this example.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int x = 30; // this is static initialization 

int main()
{
  cout << x <<  '\n`;
  x = 40; // this is an assignment
  cout << "Now it's "  << x <<  '\n';
  cin.ignore(1);
  return 0;
};
```

Comment: Re "meaningless because it's not defined when the assignment is going to happen", no, that's an invalid and misleading **rationalization**. One can easily express the assignment via an initialization of some dummy variable, e.g. `bool dummy = (x = 30, false);`. That's not meaningless, that's code with defined effect, and in the original context it's well-defined.

Comment: @Cheers Please don't move the goalposts. `bool dummy = (x = 30, false);` is not what OP wrote, it's not going to do whatever OP wanted the equivalent Python code to do, and it's not anything anyone should be telling a C++ beginner to do.

Comment: (1) You're moving the goalposts. (2) Of course it's not what the OP wrote. (3) It does what the OP wanted the Python code to do. (4) Agreed that one should not tell beginners to do that, but that sounds as if I'd done that, which is incorrect. (5) The list of incorrect assertions in your response is just too short, just four won't do, where's the fifth?